# Как применить событие для родительского элемента и всех дочерних (даже если на каком-то из них стоит preventDefault()) jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с ситуацией, когда нужно при клике на элементе обработать это событие специальным образом, но в дочернем элементе используется блок, на который применен плагин (Magic Zoom Plus) и он явно сбрасывает этот обработчик, так как событие уже не обрабатывается, пробовал через callback создать обработчик, после загрузки плагина - не помогло. Каким образом можно решить такую проблему?

Код примерно выглядит так:

```js
$(".class1").on('click', function() {
  alert(123);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <a class="MagicZoom" href="#">111</a> 123
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш код и так не будет работать, потому что у вас нет селектора class1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если вот так попробовать?

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('.class1');
let aTag = document.querySelector('.MagicZoom');
let clickable_items = [parent, aTag];

clickable_items.forEach(element => {
 element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(element.classList.contains('MagicZoom')) {
   e.stopPropagation();
  } else {
   console.log('clicked')
  }  
 })
})
aTag.addEventListener('click', () => {
 //Magic Zoom Event
 console.log('atag')
})
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <a class="MagicZoom" href="#">111</a> 123
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Селектор контейнера + всех его дочерних элементов

```
$('.snippet-code,.snippet-code *')
```

Только такой подход неправильный, событие и так распространяется снизу вверх для jQuery. Попробуйте добавить аттрибут `onclick` - его вызов будет в первую очередь. Также можно ловить событие [сверху вниз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922682#answer-29923421) .